# Show that $\operatorname{Cl}(A)\setminus A$ consists of entirely of accumulation points of $A$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset M$. Show that $\operatorname{Cl}(A)\setminus A$ consists of entirely of accumulation points of $A$, where $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ is the closure of $A$.

My attempt:

Suppose $x \in \operatorname{Cl}(A)\setminus A$ is not an accumulation point, $\exists$ $\epsilon > 0$, s.t. $B(x, \epsilon)\cap A$ is empty, i.e. $B(x, \epsilon) \subset A^c$.

I do not know where to go from here; I was hoping to show that either $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ could be even smaller or that $x \notin \operatorname{Cl}(A)\setminus A$ (a contradiction either way).

I appreciate any help. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Cl} (A)/A$?

Comment: The set that has any points in the closure of A but not in A itself.

Comment: You denote it like a quotient, not as a set difference.

Comment: accumulation point = limit point? Maybe define it?

Comment: @Bernard Which would be how? It seems fine to me. It’s understandable within set theory imo since you don’t have to know about groups or quotients or whatever.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma An accumulation point of $A$ is a point such that any ball centered at it has at least one point of $A$. My understanding is that a limit point is the same but with infinitely many points in $A$ in any ball around the point.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: It should be more or less as I edited it. The command is usually `\setminus` or `\smallsetminus`, or at a pinch a simple `—` will do.

Comment: If every ball centred at $x$ contains a point of $A$, $x$ is called an adherent point, if we always have a point $\neq x$ in $A$ it's called a limit point, if it always contains infinitely many points of $A$, it's called an accumulation point. In metric spaces the last two are in fact equivalent notions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that $x$ is not an accumulation point of the set $M$ means that there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap M\subseteq\{x\}$.

You're making a mistake in negating the definition of accumulation point:

> $x$ is an accumulation point of $M$ if (and only if), for every $\varepsilon>0$, $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap M$ contains a point *distinct* from $x$.

It's easier if you do a direct proof. Suppose $x\in\operatorname{Cl}(A)\setminus A$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. Then $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap A\ne\emptyset$ by definition of closure. If $y\in B(x,\varepsilon)\cap A\ne\emptyset$, then $y\ne x$, because $y\in A$ and $x\notin A$.

But your idea, with the fix, still works: suppose $x\notin A$ is not an accumulation point of $A$; then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap A\subseteq\{x\}$. Since $x\notin A$, we conclude that $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap A=\emptyset$ and therefore $x\notin\operatorname{Cl}(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in \operatorname{Cl}(A) \setminus A$. Then every $B(x,r)$ intersects $A$ (as $x \in \operatorname{Cl}(A)$) but $B(x,r)$ must intersect $A$ in another point than $x$ (because $x \notin A$, trivially). Ergo, $x \in A'$.

Answer (score 0):

First $\operatorname{cl}A=A\cup A'$.

Thus $\operatorname{cl}A\setminus A=(A\cup A')\setminus A=A'\setminus A\subset A'$.